# How to notify when a Camel seda queue is complete?

Tags: java, apache-camel

The use case is that I have a `zip` file containing many `csv` files. Each line in each file is then sent to a `seda` queue for processing. The problem I'm having is that I'd like to know when every line has been processed by the `seda` queue to perform some other work. I'm not sure how to approach this. Currently, I'm investigating using polling to test when the `seda` queue is empty, but this could produce false results if the lines get processed faster than they arrive.

### Code

I have a class that unzips the `zip` file and reads each file as an `InputStream`. Each line in the file is then sent to a producer which in turn is sent to a `seda` queue.

```
@Component
public class CsvProcessor { 
    @Resource(name = "csvLineProducer")
    ProducerTemplate producer;

    public void process(InputStream flatFileStream) throws IOException {
        if (flatFileStream==null) return;

        try {
            LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(flatFileStream, "UTF-8");
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                final String recordLine = it.nextLine();
                this.producer.send(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange outExchange) {
                        outExchange.getIn().setBody(recordLine);
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(flatFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the camel config.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
    <template id="csvLineProducer" defaultEndpoint="seda:flatRecordStream"/>

    ...

    <route>
        <from uri="seda:flatRecordStream" />
        <bean ref="myProcessor" method="processLine" />
    </route>

    ...

</camelContext>
```

Comment: Dont use SEDA for this. Use a splitter with parallel processing set to true. The end result of the splitter will be a completed message.